# Contain an image in div

Tags: html, css

I have 4 pictures with sizes of 500x500. The problem I'm having is that the last picture spans off the page making unnecessary space. How do I contain it from spanning off the page?

HTML:

```
<div id="collage">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src=https://www.roys.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/FASHION/MENSWEAR-AW16-JOULES-COAT.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b1/5e/38/b15e38cd4864c85a52897d906a88710c.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src=https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56b6a4bd07eaa0d2d0eddb7f/58678682bebafb6e8b0a4e2a/5867868b893fc0dff9edd97d/1483179664063/Andrew+Belliot-011.jpg?format=500w>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#collage img {
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Is this according to certain resolutions? An example would be great.

Comment: @zurfyx The last image spans off the page to the right making white space for the whole page. Like I have 4 pictures and I want to size them so that they properly fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the **.img-responsive** class, like this:

```
<div id="collage">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=https://www.roys.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/FASHION/MENSWEAR-AW16-JOULES-COAT.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b1/5e/38/b15e38cd4864c85a52897d906a88710c.jpg>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56b6a4bd07eaa0d2d0eddb7f/58678682bebafb6e8b0a4e2a/5867868b893fc0dff9edd97d/1483179664063/Andrew+Belliot-011.jpg?format=500w>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason when I make the Div section with the row and columns, it produces a white space on the left and shifts everything almost like there is padding.

Answer (score 0):

Making image tag max-width to 100% like following css code will solve your problem.

`#collage img { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```css
#collage img {
  width: 100%;
}
```